# What was the historical impact of Ariane 5's Flight 501?

Tags: testing, history, bug

The disintegration of the Ariane 5 rocket 37 seconds after launch on her maiden voyage ([Flight 501](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501)) is commonly referred to as one of the [most expensive software bugs in history](http://www.around.com/ariane.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> It took the European Space Agency 10 years and $7 billion to produce Ariane 5, a giant rocket capable of hurling a pair of three-ton satellites into orbit with each launch and intended to give Europe overwhelming supremacy in the commercial space business.
>
> All it took to explode that rocket less than a minute into its maiden voyage last June, scattering fiery rubble across the mangrove swamps of French Guiana, was a small computer program trying to stuff a 64-bit number into a 16-bit space.
>
> One bug, one crash. Of all the careless lines of code recorded in the annals of computer science, this one may stand as the most devastatingly efficient. From interviews with rocketry experts and an analysis prepared for the space agency, a clear path from an arithmetic error to total destruction emerges.

What major changes did Flight's 501 failure and the subsequent investigations inspire to the research of safety critical systems and software testing?

I'm not looking for an explanation of the bug itself, but for an explanation of the historical impact of the bug, in terms of research that were inspired from or were directly related to the investigation(s) of the failure. For example this [paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1998ESASP.422..201L) concludes:

> We have used static analysis to:
>
> - check the initialization of variables,
> - provide the exhaustive list of potential data access conflicts for shared variables,
> - exhaustively list the potential run time errors from the Ada semantics.
>
> **To our knowledge this is the first time boolean-based and non boolean-based static analysis techniques are used to validate industrial programs.**

Similarly, [this paper](http://spiderman-2.laas.fr/IFIPWG/Workshops&Meetings/40/5-Cousot.pdf)<sup>(pdf)</sup> notes:

> Abstract interpretation based static program analyses have been used for the
> static analysis of the embedded ADA software of the Ariane 5 launcher and
> the ARD. The static program analyser aims at the automatic detection of
> the deﬁniteness , potentiality, impossibility or inaccessibility of run-time errors
> such as scalar and ﬂoating-point overﬂows, array index errors, divisions by zero
> and related arithmetic exceptions, uninitialized variables, data races on shared
> data structures, etc. The analyzer was able to automatically discover the Ariane
> 501 ﬂight error. **The static analysis of embedded safety critical software (such
> as avionic software) is very promising**.

I would love a thorough explanation of the impact this single event had on software testing approaches and tools.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The $7 billion figure possibly refers to the total cost of the Ariane 5 project, Wikipedia reports that the failure resulted in a loss of more than $370 million. Still a quite expensive failure but nowhere near the $7 billion figure.</sub>

Comment: Define "worst"... Worst because it was expensive? I don't know... I think the Therac-25 would have be a much worse bug if you were one of the people subjected to massive overdoses of radiation during cancer treatment. http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/SWE/Papers/THERAC25.html ; http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3604/lib/Therac_25/Therac_1.html ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Answering your own question is _perfectly acceptable_, we even got a [feature recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) that encourages self answers. I was going to test drive it for this question, however given that this is a contest question (not that it has a chance) I decided to let someone else answer it.

Comment: Do we really want to establish that didactic questions are in scope? If so, I can see a wave of mildly annoying questions meant to lead us somewhere and teach us something without the OP really needing an answer. Up to you, but it seems risky.

Comment: @YannisRizos: No it doesn't *bother* me, I just find it strange. I've answered my own questions on StackOverflow, but that was a situation where I *didn't* the answer at the time I asked, I only discovered the answer after I did a lot of research, and since others had indicated interest in the question, I shared the solution I found. To ask a question when you already know the answer seems a bit silly, does it not?

Comment: @Ryathal The way I read the quote, the $7 billion figure is the total cost of the Ariane project, while the $370 million on Wikipedia possibly refers to the cost of the one rocket. Anyways, it certainly the $7 billion figure is certainly in USD, the quote is from the New York Times Magazine.

Comment: @CorbinMarch I honestly don't have a good answer to that, other than pointing you to the [official answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). We fight waves of mildly annoying questions daily, I don't think the feature or the approach will change that.

Comment: Yannis I would be interested to see reasoning under the idea that _static code analysis is the answer_; [references I studied so far](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149888/what-was-the-historical-impact-of-ariane-5s-flight-501#comment284086_149893 "listed here") don't indicate that this is indeed the case

Comment: @gnat Never said it was the _only_ answer, just a hint that the question has an answer to appease the close voters. But here you go: http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1998ESASP.422..201L/0000201.000.html & http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=263750 (ACM paywall)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Sometimes I have questions for which __I think__ I know the answer, but I am not sure. So I would like to ask them, not to have my thesis confirmed, but rather being open for all kinds of answers I am going to get. So, in general, I think it makes sense to ask a question even if I have already some ideas regarding possible answers.

Comment: @CrazyEddie As discussed on [Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/are-programming-related-history-trivia-questions-acceptable-on-p-se), history questions that are non trivial _are_ on topic and this particular question _is_ answerable. As for the practical part, the reason I'm looking for a solid answer to this is to understand how a single infamous event affected our methodologies and approaches of software testing.

Comment: ...Yannis I think you're good to go. I'd hesitate to push static code analysis as the only / definitive answer (found some reservations in _Cousot_ and _Garlington_ worth studying) but other than that, this "version" looks pretty solid. Among other materials I studied analysis and recommendations given in [ESA Inquiry Board report on Ariane 501](http://esamultimedia.esa.int/docs/esa-x-1819eng.pdf) - there seem to be no red flags there that would somehow dismiss your idea

Comment: @gnat Give me a great answer then ;) I _know_ my premise is correct (long discussions about it with my professors), but that doesn't qualify as a great answer. Also I wouldn't dare say that there is a single definitive answer to this, but I will say that there is a **very** small set of very specific and well defined answers.

Comment: @Yannis Not trying to start a flamewar or anything, but I just noticed the existence of [SE "contests"](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/programmers-se-contest-the-complete-outline). Is this question seriously motivated by curiosity about the topic, or was it just an excuse to participate in the contest? I ask because, as **FrustratedWithFormsDesigner** commented, it looks like a question-with-its-answer rolled into one :/

Comment: @AndresF. That's a fair concern: 1) I was saving the question for the contest, but only because I was hoping the extra traffic would help me get the great answer I'm looking for, 2) At the time I posted this (and now) I had the two leading answers in contest eligible questions, the top one is at +50 so in all likelihood I've already won for the week (the previous winning answers were at +32 and +19), 3) I posted the answer _after_ I hit the rep cap for the day, so I didn't even get any rep for it.

Comment: @AndresF. (cont..) And lastly, I only edited in my answer after the question started getting close votes, in an attempt to prove that the question is indeed answerable. If you feel the two papers sufficiently answer the question, feel free to post an answer based around them and edit them out of the question, the whole point of the question is to be sufficiently answered. It won't be the great answer I'm looking for, but it can get there if you expand it with further references and perhaps something I'm missing. I'm 99% certain I'm missing something, which is, well, why I'm asking.

Comment: @Yannis Fair enough. The topic (the Ariane disaster and its software engineering consequences) is a genuinely interesting topic. I was just wondering about your motivation... I'm satisfied by your reply.

Comment: @AndresF. The "feel free to post an answer" is completely honest, if you have the energy to post a full answer, please go for it. You could also use gnat's reference, a few comments up.

Comment: Yannis, wrt reservations I mentioned, _Garlington_ points out that besides technical issues, ESA report also lists those considered as "process" and "management approach". As for _Cousot_, he explains some shortcomings of static program analysis - although he mentions that Ariane 5 / avionics software lie withing its applicability boundaries ([Abstract Interpretation Based Formal Methods and Future Challenges](http://spiderman-2.laas.fr/IFIPWG/Workshops&Meetings/40/5-Cousot.pdf), chapter 3.2). Note these are mere reservations, I found nothing like outright dismissal - not even close

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, it was more a case of "[software rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot)".  The flight control software was recycled from the earlier Ariane 4 rocket, a sensible move given how expensive it is to develop software, especially when it's mission critical software which must be tested and verified to far more rigorous standards than most commercial software needs to be.

Unfortunately, nobody bothered testing what effect the change in operating environment would have, or if they did they didn't do said testing to a sufficiently thorough standard.

The software was built to expect certain parameters to never exceed certain values (thrust, acceleration, fuel consumption rates, vibration levels, etc).  In normal flight on an Ariane 4 this wasn't a problem because those parameters would never reach invalid values without something already being spectacularly wrong.  The Ariane 5, however, is much more powerful and ranges that would seem to be silly on the 4 could quite easily happen on the 5.

I'm not sure what parameter it was that went out of range (it might have been acceleration, I'll have to check), but when it did, the software was unable to cope and suffered an arithmetic overflow for which there had been insufficient error checking and recovery code implemented.  The guidance computer started sending garbage to the engine nozzle gimbals, which in turn started pointing the engine nozzle pretty much randomly.  The rocket started to tumble and break up, and the automatic self-destruct system detected the rocket was now in an unsafe irrecoverable attitude and finished the job.

To be honest, this incident probably didn't teach any new lessons, as the kind of problems have been unearthed before in all manner of systems, and there are already strategies in place to deal with finding and fixing errors.  What the incident did do was ram home the point that being lax in following those strategies can have enormous consequences, in this case millions of dollars of destroyed hardware, some extremely pissed off customers and an ugly dent in the reputation of Arianespace.

This particular case was especially glaring because a shortcut taken to save money ended up costing a huge amount, both in terms of money and lost reputation.  If the software had been tested just as robustly in an Ariane 5 simulated environment as it had been when it was originally developed for Ariane 4, the error surely would have come to light long before the software was installed in launch hardware and put in command of an actual flight.  Additionally, if a software developer had deliberately thrown some nonsense input into the software then the error might have even been caught in the Ariane 4 era, as it would have highlighted the fact that the error recovery that was in place was inadequate.

So in short, it didn't really teach new lessons, but it rammed home the dangers of not remembering old ones.  It also demonstrated that the environment within which a software system operates is every bit as important as the software itself.  Just because the software is verifiably correct for environment X doesn't mean it's fit for purpose in the similar but distinct environment Y.  Finally it highlighted how important it is for mission critical software to be robust enough to deal with circumstances that shouldn't have happened.

Contrast flight 501 with Apollo 11 and its computer problems.  Whilst the LGC software suffered from a serious glitch during the landing, it was designed to be extremely robust and was able to remain in an operational state in spite of the software alarms that were triggered, without putting any astronauts in danger and still being able to complete its mission.

Comment: References....?

Comment: My own memories of engineering ethics lectures when studying computer science at university :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem was caused by omitting some asserts at a place deemed okay for Ariane 4, because its (inertial navigation) computer would be overloaded had the asserts been presents. Ariane 5 had much more powerful computer to do the job which would have handled the asserts easily, but they hadn't been reenabled.

Answer (score 1):

It was mostly a reuse problem and management problem and not a coding one. From my recollections (I'm problably getting some things wrong) of the report.

- one subsystem had been designed for Ariane IV. Trajectories of Ariane IV could not result in the overflow and it was then purposely decided that if it occured, it was an hardware problem and shutting down the subsystem and going to the spare was the right thing to do.
- for Ariane V, it was decided to reuse that subsystem and not to review the assumptions and the code but rely on testing.
- further it was decided to drop full testing.

Different flight parameters of Ariane V made the overflow occurs. Shut down the primary. Shut down the spare. Autodestruction.

Additional things I remember:

- the subsystem at the time of overflow was no more useful. One could argue that its failure shouldn't have triggered the autodestruction. (On the other hand, the added complexity could itself be a source of problems).
- there was debug data sent to a bus when it shouldn't. I don't remember the specific.

Comment: Ah, I know what the bug was, that's not really my question. I've oftenly heard that the bug changed our approach to software testing, and that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: [version of "reuse problem"](http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/contract/ariane/) has been [thoroughly challenged by Ken Garlington](http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~herbert/CS4504/G%20Software%20FomalVerification/Critique%20of%20Put%20it%20in%20the%20contract%20The%20lessons%20of%20Ariane%20-%20Ken%20Garlington%2016%20Mar%2098.htm);  Bashar Nuseibeh also [argued that it's more "risk management" problem than that of reuse](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ban/pubs/ariane5.pdf)

Comment: ISTR the mechanism behind the failure was that the code threw an overflow exception, which the caller didn't catch.  The exception was propagated up until it was caught by the default exception handler, which aborted the offending module.  However, since the exception had percolated up so many levels, the "offending module" at that point was the entire RSI (inertial reference system).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it caused the industry in general to re-examine the concept of re-use, and place it in a larger frame of reference whereby components are not evaluated in isolation but in the context of the whole system.  This significantly reduces the attractiveness of re-use, since even if a component can be re-used without changes, it still has to be analyzed with a new set of assumptions.  Another corollary is that backup hardware running the same software is not nearly as attractive, since most modern hardware is orders of magnitude more reliable than modern software.  I have heard that some defense contracts require two separate software systems developed by different teams using different technologies working from the same specification to verify proper implementation.

Comment: References please...

Comment: Mostly half-remembered from an old ACM article, but some more information is [here](http://www.leshatton.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Ariane5_STQE499.pdf).

Comment: The ideas of separate computers , with code developed by different teams was used by the Space shuttle program, and maybe even earlier.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep : Read up on the AT&T Exchange failure and it's outcomes. Sorry - no reference, know of it from memory.